# Reading from char device using read() with pointer to buffer

Tags: c, linux, pointers

I am working on a C program that will run in user space on an embedded ARM GNU/Linux system.  I need to read data from a char device node /dev/fpga_sram.  Within the C program, a buffer has been allocated using malloc, as shown below.

```
uint16_t *buff;
uint32_t num = 4194304 * 3;
buff = (uint16_t *)malloc(num * sizeof(uint16_t));
```

Using the read() function, I would like to read data into a certain index of the buffer, as demonstrated in the code snippet below.

```
int ret;
int fd;
int ptr_loc;

ptr_loc = 0;    
fd = open("/dev/fpga_sram", O_RDONLY);
ret = read(fd, &(buff[ptr_loc]), 4194304 * sizeof(uint16_t));
close(fd);
```

The reason why I want to do this is because the buffer needs to be filled with different reads from the device node /dev/fpga_sram at different times.  The buffer size is greater than the total number of bytes read, so I would anticipate assigning ptr_loc to another index, as demonstrated below.

```
ptr_loc = 4194304;    
fd = open("/dev/fpga_sram", O_RDONLY);
ret = read(fd, &(buff[ptr_loc]), 4194304 * sizeof(uint16_t));
close(fd);
```

However, when I try to access data stored in the buffer, I receive a segfault:

```
printf("i = 0, data = %u\n", buff[0]);   // this line of code causes segfault
```

What am I doing wrong here, and is it possible to read from the device node with a pointer to a buffer location?  I would assume that reading from the device node would be similar to reading from a file in GNU/Linux.

Comment: Did you check the return from malloc? And do you have 8Mb of RAM to malloc?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend always checking return values, e.g. malloc and open.

Comment: Are you sure you're not `read()`ing past the end of the buffer; If `ptr_loc > 1`, it looks like you are.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: I have checked the return from malloc to ensure that buff is not NULL, and I have 128 MB of RAM in total.  If I don't use a pointer, then `ret = read(fd, buff, 4194304 * sizeof(uint16_t))` works well, but the read starts at the beginning of the buffer.

Comment: @mdec: I have checked return values, but not in the simple code snippet above.

Comment: @Dave: Could you elaborate, and perhaps post a solution?

Comment: @NicholasKinar Actually, ptr_loc needs to be greater than `(4<<20)*2` for there to be a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the reading business, the only reason for the printf to produce a SEGV is that buff points someplace outside the process's valid memory.  So use printf("%p", buff) and find out where buff is pointing, and sprinkle these in your code until you find out when it stops pointing to the address that malloc returned.

Comment: You are right; the problem was related to the pointer being modified inside another function. I wrote a few test programs, and found out that reading (as demonstrated in the code snippets above) works well.  I used printf("%p", buff) throughout the code, and I was able to find the error that I made.  Thank you for pointing this out.